# PHP/HTML Show DIV of Record for a Day

Tags: php

I'm making a recipe site, I have around 8 recipes in the recipes table and they all show in the main page, but I want a "Recipes of the Day" div which shows a random recipe for that day, and then changes it to another once system time has changed,

Reference
http://allrecipes.co.uk/

I just do not know how to do this.

Below is the PHP used to show all recipes in the page

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM recipes ORDER BY recipe_id ASC";
  $result = $DBH->prepare($query);
  $result->execute();
while($recipe = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

and a random div

```
<div class="ads">Some text</div>
```

Comment: You probably need a CRON to execute each day and pick the random recipe, then store the ID of the recipe of the day somewhere.